# Can Team Foundation Server 2010 be installed on Windows 10?

Tags: tfs, windows-10

When Team Foundation Server 2010 was released, there are no Windows 10. I check its system requirements and found it supports Windows 7. So does anyone have experiences in installing TFS 2010 on Windows 10 successfully?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS 2010 doesn't support Windows 10, it only supports the following client operating systems:

- Windows 7 (Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate)
- Windows Vista SP2

More details, please refer to [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements#operating-systems).